# inconsistent resolution of "localhost" macOS Sonoma 14.4.1

Tags: network

I expect localhost to resolve to 127.0.0.1, but I get NXDOMAIN. dig and host commands also return failed DNS resolution. Why should localhost go to DNS?

```bash
nslookup localhost
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find localhost: NXDOMAIN
```

Using the macOS resolver yields the expected result:

```bash
dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

Ping `localhost` works. So does `traceroute`:

```bash
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.110 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.073/0.103/0.127/0.023 ms

traceroute to localhost (127.0.0.1), 64 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.371 ms  0.078 ms  0.059 ms
```

using curl to `http://localhost:5000` returns nothing, not even an error. Using `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000` connects as expected. curl to an address that does not resolve results in a resolution error. curl to `http://localhost` results in a:

> "failed to connect to port 80" error.

```bash
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000
Hello, World!% 

curl http://sdfjasldkfjsalkdfj.com
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sdfjasldkfjsalkdfj.com

curl http://localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

For the record, `/etc/hosts` and `/private/etc/hosts` are identical as shown here:

```bash
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

---

**Why I care about this**: I'm developing a Flask application in a devcontainer using VSCode. When I configure port forwarding for port `5000` from the devcontainer to my local machine, VSCode builds URIs of the form `http://localhost:5000` which do not work in either safari or Firefox, or in the VSCode "simple browser" because `localhost` does not resolve. I have to change it to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

I have not discovered a way to make VSCode build URIs using the loopback IP address instead.

What is going on with this?

Comment: Some additional info I've discovered:

http://localhost:5000 returns blank without an error both using curl and safari. Firefox accesses the forwarded port correctly.

Comment: Is this question about resolving localhost (you can’t) or a port being in use by an app

Answer (score -1):

macOS Sonoma has an "airplay receiver" service already listening on port 5000, thus interfering with port forwarding in VSCode.

Found the answer here: https://blog.yimingliu.com/2023/01/01/cannot-connect-to-flask-development-server-on-localhost-port-5000

Comment: Link-only answers don't last long on AskDifferent as links can disappear, making your answer superfluous. Edit your question with a copy/paste of the solution found at this link to give the OP some help.

Comment: Right now, it doesn‘t even answer the question asked (which was about localhost not resolving).